# BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress exception if run in another module

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

My BackgroundWorker works perfectly in my main form frmMain. But when I run the ReportProgress method in another module, I get exception "This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report progress. Modify WorkerReportsProgress to state that it does report progress." This IS set to report progress; this works fine when run the same way in the main module.

Basically, from a module called by my BackgroundWorker, I want to show progress on my main form.

How can I fix this? The only idea I have is to move the code from the module into my main form, but this seems a backward step, which would involve extra work. Am hoping there are easier ways!

Calling code in class frmMain:

```
Friend WithEvents BackgroundWorker As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Private Sub btnTest_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    ' Specify that we do NOT want the background operation to allow cancellation
    BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = False
    ' Specify that we want the background operation to report progress.
    BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    ' Start running the background operation by calling the RunWorkerAsync method.
    BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker.DoWork
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = MyTest()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged
    Me.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%"
    sspStatus.Text = e.UserState.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
        Handles BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        '  The background operation was cancelled
        Me.Text = "Cancelled!"
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        '  The background operation encountered an error
        Me.Text = "Error: " & e.Error.Message
    Else
        '  The background operation completed successfully
        Me.text = "Done!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Code which generates the exception in separate module Invoices:

```
Public Function MyTest() As Boolean
    frmMain.BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0)
End Function
```

Am using VB.NET in VS 2010, with .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set it up as

```
Public Function MyTest(worker as BackgroundWorker) As Boolean
    worker.ReportProgress(0)
End Function
```

to make sure you are talking to the right worker instance.

(And aside: avoid using classnames for instance fields).

Comment: Thanks Henk, this solved my problem exactly. Very easy to apply and intuitive.